# How to get public key in hex format from a X.509 certificate

Tags: openssl, cryptography, x509

Is it possible to get only the public key in hex format through openssl? I've used the command:

```
openssl x509 -in a.pem -text -noout
```

That just prints the certificate, where public key is available in hex format, but I cannot parse that. This command for instance:

```
openssl x509 -in a.pem -pubkey -noout
```

returns the public key in the following format:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
#######
####===
-----END PUBLIC KEY----
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm expecting output in a hexadecimal format.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since (after discussion) it is a self-signed key already in Base64 (Armored ASCII) format, a tool like [tomeko.net](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php) is enough to encode it in hex.

---

Original answer:

From [this article](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2009/01/01/extract-public-key-from-x509-certificate-as-hex/), for a trusted certificate:

> Parsing public keys form a X.509 certificate and representing them as a Hex number turned out simple and easy.

```
openssl x509 -modulus -noout < pub.cer | sed s/Modulus=/0x/
```

> Just replace pub.cer with the certificate file you want to parse

This uses the [modulus option](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18031).

The result should be something like:

```
0xB1E057678343....
```

---

Note: the above applies to an X.509v3 file which contain ASCII (Base64) armored data prefixed with a “—– BEGIN …” line (ie an actual PEM file).

If you get the following error it means that you are trying to view a DER encoded certificate:

```
unable to load certificate
PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:
Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

For a der file, note also that [the public key in DER format (which is a way of expressing X.509 objects as a sequence of bytes) includes more than just the modulus, but also the exponent (usually short) and the algorithm identifier](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/14494)

Convert the [certificate from DER to PEM first](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html):

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

Then try again

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But getting the error: `unable to load certificate
49367:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.30.2/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE` when tried with public key and `Modulus=Wrong Algorithm type` when tried with the certificate.

Comment: @GowthamG is your private pem cert an actual X.509v3 file which contain ASCII (Base64) armored data prefixed with a “—– BEGIN"?

Comment: Yeah, it is a `X509v3` file, it had some components like `X509v3 extensions: X509v3 Basic Constraints` and it is a self signed certificate.

Comment: And FYI it starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ends with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

Comment: That's alright, the original certificate is in pem format only.

Comment: @GowthamG Then I suppose it is because it is a self-signed instead of a trusted certificate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137826/discussion-between-gowtham-g-and-vonc).

Comment: @GowthamG can you try with `openssl rsa -modulus -noout -in <userkey.pem>` instead?